# Does Python's imaplib let you set a timeout?

Tags: python, imaplib

I'm looking at the API for Python's [imaplib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imaplib.html).

From what I can tell, there is no way to setup a timeout like you can with [smtplib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html).

Is that correct? How would you handle a host that's invalid if you don't want it to block?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `imaplib` module doesn't provide a way to set timeout, but you can set a default timeout for new socket connections via the [`socket.setdefaulttimeout`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.setdefaulttimeout):

```
import socket
import imaplib
socket.setdefaulttimeout(10)
imap = imaplib.IMAP4('test.com', 666)
```

Or you can also go about overriding the [`imaplib.IMAP4`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imaplib.html#imap4-objects) class with some knowledge from [`imaplib` source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2672e30d9095/Lib/imaplib.py) and docs, which provides better control:

```
import imaplib
import socket

class IMAP(imaplib.IMAP4):
    def __init__(self, host='', port=imaplib.IMAP4_PORT, timeout=None):
        self.timeout = timeout
        # no super(), it's an old-style class
        imaplib.IMAP4.__init__(self, host, port)

    def open(self, host='', port=imaplib.IMAP4_PORT):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.sock = socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout=self.timeout)
        # clear timeout for socket.makefile, needs blocking mode
        self.sock.settimeout(None)
        self.file = self.sock.makefile('rb')
```

Note that after creating the connection we should set the socket timeout back to `None` to get it to blocking mode for subsequent [`socket.makefile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.makefile) call, as stated in the method docs:

> ...
>   The socket must be in blocking mode (it can not have a timeout). ...

Comment: Please remove self.sock.settimeout(None), it let timeout not works and blocking always.

Answer (score 4):

```
import imaplib
...
# ssl and timeout are config values
# connection to IMAP server
if ssl:
    imapResource = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(server, port)
else:
    imapResource = imaplib.IMAP4(server, port)
# communications timeout
sock=imapResource.socket()
timeout = 60 * 5 # 5 minutes
sock.settimeout(timeout)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want `IMAP4_SSL`, we can modify 
**famousgarkin's** answer by wrapping the socket with ssl context [ssl_context.wrap_socket()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext.wrap_socket)

```
import imaplib
import socket

class IMAP(imaplib.IMAP4_SSL):
    def __init__(self, host='', port=imaplib.IMAP4_SSL_PORT, timeout=None):
        self.timeout = timeout
        # no super(), it's an old-style class
        imaplib.IMAP4_SSL.__init__(self, host, port)

    def open(self, host='', port=imaplib.IMAP4_SSL_PORT):

        sock = socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout=self.timeout)
        self.sock = self.ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=host)

        # clear timeout for socket.makefile, needs blocking mode
        self.sock.settimeout(None)
        self.file = self.sock.makefile('rb')
```